# Помогите разобраться почему происходит ошибка в post запросе и как сделать правильно? Java

Tags: java, post

делаю POST запрос по сайту https://belkacredit.ru/applica... tion/phone, необходимо отправить запрос в форму и получить ответ(откроется окно для подтверждения смс кода)

Вот форма, в которую отправляется запрос:

```
<input name="mobile_phone" type="tel" inputmode="tel" class="input not-empty" autocomplete="tel" actionname="mobile_phone" value="+7 (XXX) XXX XX XX">
```

вот как делаю в java:

```
public class BelkaCredit {
private final String URL = "https://belkacredit.ru/application/registration/phone";

void parsePhoneNumber(String number) throws IOException {

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .followRedirects(true)
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .data("phone_number", number)
            .post();
    System.out.println(doc);
}}
```

на выходе такая ошибка:

```
HTTP error fetching URL. Status=405, URL=[https://belkacredit.ru/application/registration/phone]
```

Может я что то не то делаю, прошу совета или помощи.

Comment: Ошибка _HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed_ означает, что данный HTTP метод (POST) не поддерживается соответствующим ендпойнтом.  К данному URLу можно обращаться вероятно только с помощью GET, чтобы получить страницу целиком. Используйте средства разработчика в браузере, чтобы узнать, как именно отправляется запрос с этой формы.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код потенциально может привести к исключению `java.net.MalformedURLException`, так как вы используете `Jsoup.connect(URL)`, и `URL` – это строка без проверки на корректность URL-адреса.

Чтобы избежать этой ошибки, вам нужно обернуть блок кода в try-catch и обработать `MalformedURLException`. Вот исправленный код:

```java
public class BelkaCredit {
    private final String URL = "https://belkacredit.ru/application/registration/phone";

    void parsePhoneNumber(String number) throws IOException {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                    .data("phone_number", number)
                    .post();
            System.out.println(doc);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // или обработайте исключение по вашему усмотрению
        }
    }
}
```

Также обратите внимание, что вам нужно импортировать класс `MalformedURLException`:

```java
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
```

Это позволит вам корректно обрабатывать исключения, связанные с URL-адресом.

Comment: он все равно HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed  возвращает. Запрос не обрабатывается сам( Коментатор выше писал, что нельзя там пост запрос обработать, уже и не знаю как обойти.

Comment: А библиотеки импортировали?

Comment: import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import java.io.IOException; Импортировал, но эти библиотеки эксепшенов, мне и так понятно уже какую он ошибку возвращает

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, у вас есть ошибка в теге `<input>` HTML и в параметре `data` в методе `Jsoup.connect()`. Вот исправленный код:

```html
<input name="phone_number" type="tel" inputmode="tel" class="input not-empty" autocomplete="tel" actionname="mobile_phone" value="+7 (XXX) XXX XX XX">
```

```java
public class BelkaCredit {
    private final String URL = "https://belkacredit.ru/application/registration/phone";

    void parsePhoneNumber(String number) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .followRedirects(true)
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                .data("mobile_phone", number)  // Updated parameter name to match your HTML input
                .post();
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
}


Я изменил атрибут `name` в теге `<input>` на "phone_number", чтобы он соответствовал параметру, передаваемому в методе `Jsoup.connect()`.
```

Comment: Спасибо, заметил исправил) Но: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=405, URL=[https://belkacredit.ru/application/registration/phone]